# Render ASP.NET MVC view from a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

This may be a bad idea for any number of reasons, but I still want to accomplish it. Is there a way to render a view *from* a string that contains some HTML and code blocks? My initial thought is that I would implement `IView` and have that take the HTML string in the constructor. Then pass it to the `View` method along with the model, like so:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    var str = @"<html><body><%= Model.SomeProperty %></body></html>";
    var myView = new MyIView(str);
    return View(myView, Model);
}
```

At this point I get a little stuck since I don't know how to invoke the view engine to parse the string and make it all work. Or, at this point, do I have to parse and render it myself?

Comment: He means that if SomeProperty is set by a user, they could potentially include a malicious script tag and that would get injected into your response and executed by the browser.

Comment: None of the properties in the model will be set by users. Only by admins/developers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not easy to do for ASPX pages.

In [ASP.Net Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx), it's much easier.

If you really want to do it, register a custom `VirtualPathProvider` that resolves special paths to your strings, then call `BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath`, cast it to `ViewPage`, set its `ViewData`, and call `RenderView`.

Comment: To add to SLaks answer, if all you want to do is hard code some return value in your controller then you can just build your string manually: `var str = @"<html><body>" + Model.SomeProperty + @"</body></html>"`. However if what you actually want to do is store your views in a database (instead of as a file) then you will have to implement a VirtualPathProvider that returns the contents of your database for requests to a particular path.

Comment: I have implemented a `VirtualPathProvider`, and it's working great, with one exception. The views served are unable to use a strongly typed Model. I always get `Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Model>'.`  Any ideas?

Comment: @Freyday: Change your `VirtualPathProvider` to provide your actual `bin` directory (which contains the compiled DLL with your model class).

Answer (score 0):

You can just return `string` in your action.

```
public string MyAction() {
    return @"<html><body>" + Model.SomeProperty + @"</body></html>";
}
```

Comment: This really isn't the type of solution I'm looking for. The example included in the original question has been simplified to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.